# Difference between 'knife cookbook create' and 'chef generate cookbook'?

Tags: chef-infra

I'm struggling with the chef learning curve. What is the difference between these two commands, and why are there two of them ?

[**knife cookbook**](https://docs.chef.io/knife_cookbook.html): *The knife cookbook subcommand is used to interact with cookbooks that are located on the Chef server or the local chef-repo.*

```
$ knife cookbook create a_knife_cookbook
$ ls -a
  CHANGELOG.md 
  README.md    
  attributes
  definitions
  files
  libraries
  metadata.rb
  providers
  recipes
  resources
  templates
```

[**chef generate cookbook**](https://docs.chef.io/ctl_chef.html): *The chef generate cookbook subcommand is used to generate a cookbook.*

```
$ chef generate cookbook a_chef_cookbook
$ ls -a
  .gitignore
  .kitchen.yml
  Berksfile
  README.md
  chefignore
  metadata.rb
  recipes
  spec
  test
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`knife cookbook create` is the *legacy* way to create a cookbook, it builds the structure of a cookbook with all possible directories.

`chef generate cookbook` is part of Chef-DK and aims at generating a testable cookbook structure with minimal directories to use in test-kitchen.

Both can be tweaked, the `chef generate` is easiest to tweak as the command has been written in this way to allow all to build the cookbook structure that better fits their needs.

Answer (score -1):

knife cookbook create apache-knife
WARN: This command is being deprecated in favor of `chef generate cookbook` and will soon return an error.

The knife cookbook create command has been depreciated and you can only use ''chef generate cookbook''